# convert server datetime to millisecond

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
    function validateDate()
            {
                var dateDifference;
                pickedDate = Date.parse(txtDate.value.replace(/-/g, " "));
                todaysDate = new Date();
                todaysDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                dateDifference = Math.abs(Number(todaysDate) - pickedDate);
                //7 Days=604800000ms//
                if (dateDifference > 604800000)
                {
                      alert("Appointment can be fixed for next seven days only from current day.");                         
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

I m getting server side date from c# in this format 2012-11-22 12:53:23
now i have to convert server datetime to millisecond for checking 7 days difference

***txtDate.value=22-Nov-2012***
```

Comment: actually on page load of master page i set datetime and acess that variable serverDateTime throughtout all the pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var time = '2012-11-22 12:53:23'; // this value is what you get from server

var a=time.split(' ');
var d=a[0].split('-');
var t=a[1].split(':');

var date = new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2]);

var millisecs = date.getTime(); // server time in milliseconds

var todayTime = (new Date()).getTime();

var diff = todayTime - millisecs; // work on this
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: var todayTime = (new Date()).getTime(); pushpesh this is from client side i want to get time from server side

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood that. But that you can easily get by passing the server time when loading the page and assign that value to `todayTime`. Javascript can't directly access server properties.

Comment: see in quetion i generate alert to understand